# Converting several arrays of corresponding information to tree-like structure of classes and subclasses

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion, tree, conceptual

I have three arrays containing different information. The first contains a list of objects, the second contains a list of the object IDs (in corresponding order with the first list), the last contains a list of the object's parent node ID (in order too).

The parent node ID of every object corresponds with another objects ID from all of the lists. But if the object doesn't have a parent node then it is a base node (parent id = -1, all other ids count up positively).

The objects themselves contain an array that can hold other objects, I need to find a way to insert the children into their parent nodes. This problem can become really complicated because the children must be inserted from top to bottom or the tree will break, meaning the base nodes have to be found first, then their children inserted, then those children inserted, etc. etc.

From looking at what you just read, you may think, recursion!!

NOPE

I tried this but javascript has limitations as to how much recursion can be done, when their are too many objects to be sorted, an exceeded stack error occurs.

For those interested in how I was solving it before, here is my code:

```
class Tree{
    constructor (indices, sorting_information){
        this.base_nodes = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < sorting_information.length; i++){
            if (!(indices.includes(sorting_information[i]))){
                var relevant_info = {
                    location: i,
                    id_num: indices[i],
                };
                var base_node = new Node(relevant_info, indices, sorting_information);
                this.base_nodes.push(base_node);
            }
        }
    }
}
class Node {
    constructor (id_info, indices, sorting_information){
        this.location = id_info.location;
        this.id = id_info.id_num;
        this.nodes = [];
        if (!(this.id == -1)){
            for (var i = 0; i < sorting_information.length; i++){
                if (sorting_information[i] == this.id){
                    var relevant_info = {
                        location: i,
                        id_num: indices[i],
                    };
                    var node = new Node(relevant_info, indices, sorting_information);
                    this.nodes.push(node);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For this code to work, only the last two lists are needed as it creates a skeletal structure that can be used to organize the first list.

A Tree instance is created with the first and second parameters of the constructor being the first and second arrays respectively. 
The constructor finds the base nodes then when the base nodes are instantiated, they find their children, etc. etc.

Expected input:

```
var nodes = [node_0, node_1, node_2, node_3, node_4, node_5, node_6];
var indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var sorting_information = [1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 4, 4]
```

Expected output:

```
var base_nodes = [node_1, node_4]; 
node_1.children = [node_0, node_2];
node_4.children = [node_5, node_6];
node_0.children = [node_3];
```

Please note that the data tree will not necessarily take up a binary form.

I have looked at this problem from many angles but keep getting a headache any help would be appreciated

Comment: Data transformation questions should always include the input and expected output of the transformation process. Please edit your question to include both.

Comment: Thanks! I just did @RandyCasburn

Comment: The problem is fairly simple if the `indices` array is in sorted order with no gaps (as shown in the example). If the `indices` array is not sorted and/or has gaps, then you need to modify the `sorting_information` array so that it corresponds to an `indices` array that is sorted and has no gaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid recursion, we can start by hashing the parent IDs to their children:

```
[1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 4, 4]

becomes

{
   1: [0, 2],
  -1: [1, 4],
   etc.
}
```

Then start at -1 and perform a search from children to children.

```js
function hash(A){
  return A.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
     acc[x] = acc[x] ? acc[x].concat(i) : [i]
     return acc
  }, {})
}

function Node(id){
  this.id = id
  this.nodes = []
}

function f(A){
  const h = hash(A) 
  const tree = new Node(-1)
  let stack = [[tree, h[-1]]]
  
  while (stack.length){
    const [parent, children] = stack.pop()
    
    for (let id of children){
      const child = new Node(id)
      parent.nodes.push(child)
      stack.push([child, h[id] || []])
    }
  }
  
  return tree
}

var A = [1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 4, 4]

console.log(JSON.stringify(f(A)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with no recursion that should account for variations on sorting_information.

This solution is based upon the **Expected Input** and the corresponding **Expected Output** from your question. It produces an array are your expected output as objects:

```js
var nodes = ['node_0', 'node_1', 'node_2', 'node_3', 'node_4', 'node_5', 'node_6'];
var indices = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
var sorting_information = [1, -1, 1, 0, -1, 4, 4];
var tree = [];

var out = sorting_information
          // Create object of ordered nodes
          .map((v, idx) => {return { node: nodes[idx], order: v}})
          // Sort on the ordering
          .sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order)
// Use a set to reduce to unique values of sorting info
let sort_set = new Set(sorting_information.sort());
// Loop through sort orders
sort_set.forEach(i=>{
   let level = (i < 0)? "base" : "node_"+i+"_children";
   // Push     filtered nodes
   tree.push({[level]: out.filter((node)=>node.order === i)
   // reduced to only the node object
   .map(node=>node.node)});
});
console.log(tree);
```